# How to access Google Cloud Platform Firestore triggers from Python runtime cloud functions

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

GCP has added support for the Python runtime to cloud functions.

GCP has also extended Firestore to the general GCP ecosystem (as opposed to solely being available for Firebase)

However, the documentation for how to listen to Firestore triggers from python cloud functions is missing, and is currently only provided for [node](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/extend-with-functions).

Is there (or will there be) a way to access Firestore triggers from python cloud functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCP has now released beta support for Python runtime functions supporting firestore triggers.

[Google Cloud Firestore Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#functions_eventdata-python)

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no support for Firestore (or other Firebase product event triggers) in Cloud Functions using Python.

There are no timelines available promising when support might be available in the future.

Answer (score 0):

After checking I saw that they have already been implemented for Python3.7. I tested it myself through the UI and it worked. I also saw this in the documentation [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#deploying_your_function) tells that it's implemented:

> *--runtime RUNTIME* - The name of the runtime you are using, such as nodejs6, nodejs8, or python37.

Remember that both Firestore triggers and CF with Python are on Beta.

NOTE: My tests were using GCP, no Firebase.